# how long does it take to find maximum element in descending sorted array?

Tags: data-analysis

Worst case to find maximum element in descending sorted array?

I guess best case, average case, and worst cases will all be same because maximum is going to be a first element.is it?

Cases will be Big-O(1)? kindly correct my speculation.

Comment: Be clear with your codes....

Answer (score 0):

if you are using iteration for search from element 1 to last then Yes.

Other wise it depends a lot on which search algorithm you are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the search algorithm and if the algorithm knows the array is already sorted. If the algorithm is unaware chances at it will be N for all cases since each element will need to be considered to prove you have the maximum.  For an aware algorithm it will probably be 1 or Log N